# Life, Death, Undead, Dead Undead, oh my!

Tags: warcraft

In the Warcraft universe, the living can be infected with a plague that turns them into undead. The undead can be killed.

My understanding of the state of undeath is that one is dead, yet some how animate, albeit it with rotting flesh. The undead seem to be alive in all ways but name. The undead can die and be resurrected, implying that they are alive.

**What precisely is the state of being undead? How is it different to being alive?**

Comment: the "world-of-warcraft" tag should really be just "warcraft", since "warcraft" encompasses the universe in it's entirety (books, comics, other games). I couldn't create a new tag or post the issue on meta because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Once you are dead, you no longer pay taxes.  So there's that advantage to undeath :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: zombies.

Undead are all entities that already died but are animated by "spiritual or supernatural forces" as cited in [WoWWiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/Undead).

How is being undead different from being alive? Well, an undead is a piece of meat controlled by an external force, not by that entity (the dead creature called undead).

Comment: The Forsaken retrieved their consciousness, though.

Comment: Actually Sylvanas freed them after she freed herself. But the Forsaken are completely dedicated to her and to their cause... so they are still under some kind of mind control (republican, democratic... etc).

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

Undead = Living Dead
The living can be killed, so the Undead can become dead.
Also, when a corpse reanimates, the corpse of the corpse doesn't leave a corpse.  As in when an animate dies, it doesn't leave any bones.